# php pdo save query data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\prjy\classes\user.php on line 34
```

Line 29-32

```
$this->sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id, userlevel FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$this->sth->bindParam(1, $username);
$this->sth->bindParam(2, $password);
$this->data = $this->sth->execute();
```

Line 34

```
if ($this->data->rowCount() > 0)
```

I want to save the result object in another variable, so I can execute another query and depending on the result, I return what is correct... Can't I save the result, (execute()) in a variable like above? How do I solve it else way?

Comment: I believe it returns a boolean, so that's why you can't use it the way you are using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDOStatement::rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last **DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

For most databases, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not return the number of rows affected
by a `SELECT` statement. Instead,
use `PDO::query()` to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement,
then use `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned.

**[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)**

Comment: What should I use for SELECT?

Comment: rowCount however does work for me now, I just had to change the variables. Is is "bad" to use it like that? I'd rather just have 2 sql statements then 4 to check if the user can login or not.

Comment: Well, that sucks.... Seriously, I just dropped all my interest for PDO.. anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about using:

```
count($this->data)
```

for the row count?

Answer (score 1):

[Matt is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619340/php-pdo-save-query-data#comment-9248898); [`PDOStatement::execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean value.

And [diEcho is <strike>partially</strike> correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619340/php-pdo-save-query-data/7619362#7619362) about [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php); the docs also say:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Seeing you are using MySQL, this *will* work, but keep in mind that this may therefor not be portable to other [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDBMS)s.

If portability is of no concern, `PDOStatement::rowCount()` is what you need and therefor you need to use this:

`if ($this->sth->rowCount() > 0)`

However, you'll need to save multiple `PDOStatement` objects. So I suggest doing something like the following:

```
$stmt1 = $this->dbh->prepare( /* first select statement */ );
$stmt1->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt1->bindParam(2, $password);

$stmt2 = $this->dbh->prepare( /* second select statement */ );
$stmt2->bindParam(1, $username);
$stmt2->bindParam(2, $password);

if( $stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute() )
{
    if( $stmt1->rowCount() > 0 )
    {
        $result = $stmt1->fetchAll();
    }
    else if( $stmt2->rowCount() > 0 )
    {
        $result = $stmt2->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Or something of similar nature, depending on what criteria you will want the results of either one of the statements.

PS.: be aware though, that in order for this to work, you would have to activate [buffered queries for MySQL in PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants) (if this wasn't activated already):

```
$db = new PDO(
          'dsn connection string',
          'username',
          'password',
          array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform another test before calling rowCount():

```
$this->sth = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT id, userlevel FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$this->sth->bindParam(1, $username);
$this->sth->bindParam(2, $password);
if($this->data = $this->sth->execute()) {
   if ($this->data->rowCount() > 0) {
      // do something here ..
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing for errors. `PDOStatement::execute()` returns `false` in case of an error. You should test for that!

```
if (!$this->data = $this->sth->execute()) { echo "ERROR!"; print_r($this->sth->errorInfo()); die(); }
```

Or something similar. That's probably the reason.